# Aspect Oriented Programming in Objective-C for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, aop

Could anyone help me first when I can use AOP, and what is it exactly in an iphone programming.

I need to access to the app project source code and call some of the functions and be notified their views loaded from outside like a library.

I found these so far, but looks very complicated to follow. Some doesnt build or the source code removed.

https://github.com/ndcube/AOP-for-Objective-C

https://github.com/moszi/AOP-in-Objective-C

ACAspect on cocoadev

Comment: It would be better if you gave a more detailed description of what you are trying to do - it may be possible using built-in Cocoa functionality such as KVO (Key Value Observing) but without a clearer explanation of the problem, I can't help you.

Comment: Your question is very ambiguous and hard to understand. What specific problem are you trying to solve, and what specific trouble are you encountering?

Comment: I am looking for a way to programatically notified that a view is loaded from outside of that viewController. I am looking for a general way, not specific to the app source code project.
I understand that to communicate between classes I could use NSNotificationCenter, or use a delegate method or tag the view, etc. But I don't want to change anything in the source code of the view controller. I want to have lets say sth like the library or framework to manage this from outside.

Comment: well, I think the question about AOP is very clear. The part about "notified their views loaded from outside like a library" is the misleading part and has led others to tell you about KVO, which is not what you want at all. I think that basically there is still no serious AOP framework in Cocoa. There is Aspectcocoa which they recommend you don't actually use in production code because it leaks memory, bloats your binaries, etc!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a specific view in a view controller and want to be notified when it is loaded, you can register for a KVO notification when that instance variable (the outlet) changes.

You'll want to read up on Key Value Observing in Cocoa. There are several methods you will need to learn how to use.

Do a search on "Introduction to Key-Value Observing Programming Guide" in the XCode docs and read that section.

Make sure you balance each call to addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context: with a call to removeObserver:forKeyPath:, or your app may crash after the observing object is deallocated.